# DELETE from table1 where column1 is greater than table2.column1 multipled by 2

Tags: mysql

Trying to remove rows that one of the columns' value is as twice as the other table.

```
select DB
delete 
from table1
where table1.id IN (select table2.id where table1.price > table2.price*2)
```

I want the query to match the `id` `column` and delete all `table1` rows that have a `table1.column1` twice as big as their counterpart in `table2.column1`.
What syntax should I be using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables in your subquery. The example below assumes both tables have a unique id column named 'id'

```
delete 
from table1
where table1.id IN (
select table2.id from table1, table2 where 
table1.id = table2.id
and
table1.price > (table2.price*2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting from `table1` matching `id` and condition `price` in `table1` greater than that of `table2`

```
DELETE FROM table1
FROM   table1 INNER JOIN ON
table1 .id = table2.id
WHERE  (table1 .price  > table2.price* 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two tables can be joined by their `id`s then just do that like:

```
select DB
delete 
from table1
where table1.id IN (
  select table2.id from table1 inner join table2 on table2.id=table1.id
  where table1.price > table2.price*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table1 where id in 
(select id from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where table1.column1 > 2*table2.column1)
```